# React hooks app works fine with the below static data but getting error while iterating the real data

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

React hooks app works fine with the below static options data passed into a dropdown select box. But while integrating to backend and iterating the data, it throws error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error. Could someone please advise what could be the issue.

```
const options = [
    { name: 'Aaaan', email:"aaan@test.com", id: 1},
    { name: 'Baaa', email:"baaa@test.com", id: 2},
    { name: 'Crooo', email:"crooo@test.com", id: 3},
    { name: 'Daaa', email:"daaa@test.com", id: 4}
  ];


TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/project/work/devchoice/src/components/nominatePerson.js:121
  118 | <div key={i}>
  119 |     <div className="row eachrecord">
  120 |     <div className="column" >
> 121 |         <label className="nomlabel">{x[i].name} <b>>></b></label>
      | ^  122 |     </div>
  123 |     <input
  124 |         required type='textarea'
View compiled
NominatePerson
C:/project/work/devchoice/src/components/nominatePerson.js:116
  113 | </div>
  114 | <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendNomination)}>
  115 | <div className="nomineesSelectedList">
> 116 |     <h4>Selected Nominees</h4>
      | ^  117 |     {manageNominees.map((x, i) =>
  118 |         <div key={i}>
  119 |             <div className="row eachrecord">
```

`NominatePerson.js`

```
const NominatePerson = () => {

    const maxOptions = 3;
    const [manageNominees, setManageNominees] = useState([]);
    const [nomRegister, setNomRegister] = useState([]);
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors }, reset} = useForm();


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            // const email = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
            try {
                const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/nomineeslist');
                setManageNominees(res.data);
                console.log("Get the list of nominees :" + res.data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
        const copy = [...manageNominees];
        copy.push(e);
        setManageNominees(copy);
    };

    const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
        const copy = [...manageNominees];
        let index = copy.indexOf(e);
        copy.splice(index, 1);
        setManageNominees(copy);
        const updateList = nomRegister.map((item) => {
            return { ...item };
        });
        //delete the specific array case depends on the id
        updateList.splice(index, 1);
        setNomRegister(updateList);
    };

    const sendNomination = () => {
        console.log("Arry has: "+JSON.stringify(nomRegister));
    };

    manageNominees.forEach(option=>{
        option.displayValue=option.name+"\t"+option.email;
    })

    const handleChange = (e, i) => {
        const { name, email, value } = e.target;
        const updateList = nomRegister.map((item) => {
            return { ...item };
        });

        const emailList = selectedOption.map((x, j) => {
           return x[j].email;
        });
        //change the specific array case depends on the id
        updateList[i] = { ...updateList[i], name: name, email:emailList[i], reason: value };
        setNomRegister(updateList);
    };
  
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="navbar-nav">
                <div className="leftNavItem">
                    <a><Link to={'/dashboard'} className="nav-link"> <b>Dashboard</b> </Link></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Nominate a person</h1>
            <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
                <div id="dialog2" className="triangle_down1"/>
                <div className="arrowdown">
                    <Multiselect
                        onSelect={handleTypeSelect}
                        onRemove={handleTypeRemove}
                        options={manageNominees.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : manageNominees}
                        displayValue="displayValue"
                        showCheckbox={true}
                        emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
                    />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="nominationcount">
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendNomination)}>
            <div className="nomineesSelectedList">
                <h4>Selected Nominees</h4>
                {manageNominees.map((x, i) =>
                    <div key={i}>
                        <div className="row eachrecord">
                        <div className="column" >
                            <label className="nomlabel">{x[i].name} <b>>></b></label>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            required type='textarea'
                            placeholder="Please provide reason for nomination.."
                            key={i}
                            id={i}
                            name={x[i].name}
                            className='nomineechoosed'
                            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                        />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="buttongroup">
                        <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        <input id="Cancel" type="button" value="Cancel"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default NominatePerson
```

[image]

Comment: `x` is the _object_. Did you mean `x.name`, or (unnecessary but would work anyway) `manageNominees[i].name`?

Comment: here `manageNominees` is an array use like this `x.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` in the callback function of `map` is the object.
`manageNominees.map((x, i) =>{console.log(x)});` will print the complete object for you.

See the doc for [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Now the error you are seeing is because `name` is not found on `x`. So you should try to set `{x?.name}`.

Edit: as Ala Hamadi mentioned in comment, `?.` is optional chaining which helps in checking whether property/key exists on nested object.

See the doc for [optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: +  It is recommended to use the [optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to check for nullity before accessing nested objects.

Comment: @AlaHamadi Thank you, would like to clarify one thing...when I look on the `manageNominees` it is an array and I can see the data. Then why the name appears not found ? When we use the same in the `{x?.name}` will it print all of the array records ? It should display `name` and `text area` based on our selection from drop down...

Comment: @AlaHamadi This is displaying all of the records while we are on the screen. System should allow to display the name and textarea by selecting each value from the drop down..

Comment: Yes, the `.map()` method allows you to iterate over an array one by one and we do the `?.` because our array could be undefined at the beginning.

Comment: Ok but i would like to display the ``name, text`` area based on the selection item from the drop down

Comment: @AlaHamadi Thank you for the reply, I have created a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-ardinghelli-nf9s3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could you please have a look, it should display record based on the selection of each name ( maximum of 3 selection) from the drop down...Now it is iterating and displaying all of the records

Comment: Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-gates-78ti0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235932/discussion-between-soccerway-and-ala-hamadi).